# how to avoid \n being converted to space when echo a variable in bash script?

Tags: bash, echo, fifo

I have one file a with content:

```
hola
hallo
hello
```

I wrote this script to read its content:

```
#!/bin/bash
l=`cat a`
echo $l | hexdump -C #this line is only for debugging
#another program will use the content of $l after I write $l to a fifo
echo $l > my_fifo &
#program reads my_fifo
......
```

its content was changed after the first echo:

```
00000000  68 6f 6c 61 20 68 61 6c  6c 6f 20 68 65 6c 6c 6f  |hola hallo hello|
00000010  0a                                                |.|
```

actually it should be:

```
$ cat a | hexdump -C
00000000  68 6f 6c 61 0a 68 61 6c  6c 6f 0a 68 65 6c 6c 6f  |hola.hallo.hello|
00000010  0a                                                |.|
```

I dont think using "sed 's/ /\n/g'" to replace all spaces is a good idea, because my input-file is actually not so simple. how to keep it unchanged after echo?

Comment: Another one within seconds.  Use quotes around your variable names while expanding!

Comment: `echo "$l"` and not `echo $l`.

Comment: thanks, that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use double quotes to avoiding replaces of the `\r to [space](/questions/tagged/space) when using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) evaluation or assignments, or [strip](/questions/tagged/strip) operations::

```
echo "$l" | hexdump -C
00000000  68 6f 6c 61 0a 68 61 6c  6c 6f 0a 68 65 6c 6c 6f  |hola.hallo.hello|
00000010  0a
```